# Recover Windows 8 after installing Kali Linux (GRUB)

Tags: grub2, kali-linux

I've installed Kali Linux over Windows 8; Kali is installed in a separate ext4 partition (sda2) and Windows in sda1. Now GRUB is not finding Windows 8 on startup!

I can see Windows 8 with the `os-prober` command.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you haven't actually installed *over* Windows and that `0s-prober` can indeed see a Windows installation, you just need to reinstall GRUB so it will detect Windows:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

I am not familiar with Kali so if the above command is not available, use this instead:

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This will detect your installed operating systems and update GRUB to provide access to them.

Comment: @albertpaulp, you're very welcome. If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: I thought I already done that, it's done now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to select in the bios the option to boot from uefi
(windows boot manager or something like that) .

that way, when you select the legacy support you use grub to boot the linux partition, and when you select the uefi boot you go directly to windows.